# Adding animation to a ListView in order to expand/collapse content

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a list view which uses a custom adapter in order to show my custom content. Its layout is the following.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemimage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemdescription"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>    
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemtext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="TEXT CONTENT"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like that the listview only showed the view with the ids itemimage and item description, keeping the itemtext hidden.
The idea is to have a onclicklistener on each item of the list, in order to expand that item so it shows the itemtext content. I know I should use Tweening animation in order to expand/collapse each item, but I can't figure out how to do that.

If you need more code snippets, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi, did you figure it out finally? I would be interested in the solution.

Answer (score 8):

To do that, I built an Animation class, which animates the margin to negative values, making the item disappear.

The animation looks like this:

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

        // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

        // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
    }
}
}
```

I have an entire example app for this animation on my blog [post](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/expanding-listview-items/)

Answer (score 0):

Tried Udinic's solution, but finally chose this alternative:

res/anim/scale_down.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<scale
    android:duration="700"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
</set>
```

Animate ListView implementation:

```
protected void animateView(final View v, final int animResId, final int endVisibility){
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            animResId);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            v.setVisibility(endVisibility);
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });
    v.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Example calls to animate my ListView (or any View child class):

```
animateView(listView1, R.anim.scale_down, View.GONE);
animateView(listView1, R.anim.scale_up, View.VISIBLE);
```

It is working on my KitKat phone.