# Custom expandable list in android

Tags: android

I need to design the page like the image I attached below. I need to expand two views like accordion. I goggled but I am able to saw only the expandable list view. Can anyone advice me about how to custom two views in one expandable window.

Comment: Look at this [answer][1].

I hope it helps you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729830/expand-listview-item-with-animation

Answer (score 0):

If you have to expand only 2 views, then perhaps you can use a simple trick to achieve this without `ExpandableListView`.
Just define the layout of every category and subcategory in a `LinearLayout` oriented `vertically`, with the the visibility of subcategories by default to be `gone`.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/category1"
   //....>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/subcategory1"
   android:visibility="gone"
   //....>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/category2"
   //....>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/subcategory2"
   android:visibility="gone"
   //....>
</LinearLayout>
```

Set a click listener for each category, and when a category is clicked change its visibility: to `visible` if it's `gone`, and to `gone` if it's `visible`.

A pseudo cod will look like this:

```
ViewGroup category1 = findViewById(category1);
ViewGroup subcategory1 = findViewById(subcategory1);

category1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(){
        toogle();
    }
});

//......
void toogle(){
  if(subcategory1 is visible){
     subcategory1.visibility = "gone"
  }else{
     subcategory1.visibility = "visible"
  }
}
```

In case in the future the requirements will change and you'll have to add more categories, then perhaps the `ExpandableListView` would make more sense, but for now you can achieve the desired effect with this simple trick.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use SlideExpandableListView library, here you can find all details: [here](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView)